Impact of Reordering Composite Index on PostgreSQL: Performance, Space, and Overhead Considerations
I am optimizing SQL query performance by reordering a composite index in PostgreSQL. I need to understand potential repercussions, including space usage, data saving overhead, and any other impacts of this modification.
To address performance issue, I have implemented an approach involving reordering the composite index.
Details: Database: PostgreSQL Table Name: readingTable DDL Statement:
    CREATE TABLE readingTable (
    ts timestamp NOT NULL,
    plant_id int8 NOT NULL,
    instance_type varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    instance_id int8 NOT NULL,
    readings jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT idx_readingTable_pk PRIMARY KEY (ts, plant_id, instance_type, instance_id));
CREATE INDEX readingTable_ts_idx ON readingTable USING btree (ts DESC);

Table Data fromat:



ts
plant_id
instance_type
instance_id
readings




2024-05-31 23:59:00.000
4
ALARM
1765
[{"c": "ALARM_TAG_1", "d": "NUMBER", "s": "S15", "u": "kW/kWp", "v": null}, {"c": "ALARM_TAG_2", "d": "BOOLEAN", "s": "S00", "u": "AU", "v": "false"}, {"c": "ALARM_TAG_3", "d": "NUMBER", "s": "S00", "u": "kW/kWp", "v": "12.25"}]



Query:
SELECT *
FROM readingTable, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(readings) AS readings_data
WHERE plant_id = 2
  AND instance_type = 'ALARM'
  AND instance_id IN (1765)
  AND ts BETWEEN '2024-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2024-05-30 23:59:00.000'
  AND readings_data ->> 'c' IN ('ALARM_TAG_1')
ORDER BY ts, instance_id;

If I run the above query for idx_readingTable_pk(ts, plant_id, instance_type, instance_id)then it take time to execute query so I have updated the idx_readingTable_pk from (ts, plant_id, instance_type, instance_id) To (plant_id, instance_type, instance_id, ts).
In the updated index, I have reordered the sequence of the composite key because when a condition includes equality checks (=) and range/inequality checks (>, >=, <, <=, IN), the columns involved in equality checks should appear first in the index, with the inequality columns following.
Query to update idx_readingTable_pk:
-- Drop the old primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE readingTable
DROP CONSTRAINT idx_readingTable_pk;

-- Add the new primary key constraint with the updated column order
ALTER TABLE readingTable
ADD CONSTRAINT idx_readingTable_pk PRIMARY KEY (plant_id, instance_type, instance_id,ts);

This modification has led to an improvement in performance, as shown by the below statistics. In the image below, you can see that I have tested the query with both the old and new indexes across various date ranges, and you can observe the performance improvement.

Questions:

When the first executed the query to update the composite key order, does it update
the existing index, create a new one, or both?
Are there any space complexities involved, such as increased space requirements for
storing the updated index compared to the old one?
Does reordering the index introduce any overhead when saving data?
Are there any other potential repercussions of modifying the composite index that I
should be aware of?


Indexes are updated whenever you modify the table. If it were re-created from scratch, the performance would be unbearable.
The new index will have approximately the same size as the old one.  It will be smaller initially, because it has no bloat yet, but the sizes should even out over time.
The order of the columns in the index doesn't affect the performance of creating or updating the index.
Changing the order of the index columns can have enormous effects on the performance of your queries. For example, this query:
SELECT plant_id, instance_type
FROM readingtable
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2024-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2024-07-02 00:00:00';

would be very fast with the original primary key, but much slower with the new primary key.

Thank you so much for your detailed reply!
I have a couple of follow-up questions:

Does reordering the index columns introduce any overhead or performance impact during data insertion operations? In other words, will inserts be slower due to the new index order?
In a production environment, if I drop the old primary key constraint (idx_readingTable_pk) and then create a new one with the same name, can the table still execute queries during this index modification process?

Thanks again for your insights!

I addressed the first question in my answer. About the second one: if you want to avoid down time, you can create the second index CONCURRENTLY, then drop the primary key and turn the unique index into a new primary key.

Thank you for your response

I am using TimescaleDB and hypertables to manage time series data in the readingtable. Chunks are created based on the timestamp; one chunk contains data in a specific date range, for example (range start - 2021-11-04 05:30:00.000 +0530 and range end - 2021-11-11 05:30:00.000 +0530). Does reordering indexes influence the creation or management of hypertables or their associated chunks? Additionally, are there any other potential impacts on hypertable performance? Specifically, after reordering an index, does the efficiency of the hypertable remain intact?

You are a very worried person. As I wrote, the speed of creating or maintaining the index is not affected at all. The only effect might be that some queries suddenly perform much worse.

Thank you for your response
